# Media Query not working on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, media-queries, html-email

I"m doing an html email and my Android 4.2.2 (Nexus 4) phone is not picking up any of the media queries I've tried. Note that litmus.com (which renders screenshots of the email on different devices) shows that the media queries DO work atleast on Android 4.0.

I've tried:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
@media only screen and (max-width: 2000px) {}
@media only screen {}
```

Nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just found this which appears to still apply: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7158/android-gmail-42-finally-getting-media-query-support-retracted/

Comment: Gmail does not support media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which mobile email client are you using? Media queries do not work in gmail on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here.
The bad news is that as far as i could tell, the only property read from the media query was width, so while a 100% wide table will display fine, try adjusting text size or making your links "thumb-ready" and you'll be out of luck.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/topic/7636/new-gmail-app-supports-media-queries-hooraoh/